# QT "relocation error"/"no version information available" runtime errors

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian

After updating my Debian 8.9 packages I can't run my QT app. The error is:

```
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so.5: no version information available (required by ./my_app)
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: no version information available (required by ./my_app)
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5: no version information available (required by ./my_app)
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5: no version information available (required by ./my_app)
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by ./my_app)
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by ./my_app)
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by ./my_app)
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5: no version information available (required by ./my_app)
./my_app: relocation error: ./my_app: symbol qt_version_tag, version Qt_5.6 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference
```

I recompiled my app, purged/installed again qt5 and other several things found on SO, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like somebody had a similar problem there: https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/issues/189

He fixed it by checking qtchooser --print-env and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

(In the meantime Debian had released some Updates, did your Error go away with updating Debian?)